# When should I use "new" when creating an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, new-operator

I would like to understand the difference the "new" command does in the line 2 in code below. Because when I print the positions, the answer is the same. So I don't see the necessity to use this "new" command.

```
float[] values = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }; //In my view the easy way to do it
float[] values2 = new float[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }; //not understand why more verbose?
```

I just made a research and found some explain related to heap memory and pool. However I didn't understood why and when should use the new and when shouldn't.

Comment: You can leave off the `new X[]` part only when assigning a constant expression, where all the values are known at the time of assignment.

Comment: The explanation you found sounds more like stack vs. heap for allocating arrays in C (or C++). For Java, one is just a literal shorthand for the other, unless you wish to be explicit about the type. For instance, `int[] values = {1,2,3};` is obviously fine, but `int[] values = new float[]{1,2,3};` wouldn't work. For this same reason, `int[] values = {1.2, 3.4, 5.6}` also would fail (but a little less obviously, the required type in the array is now `int`). You can assign variables using the literal as well: `void foo(int s) { int[] values = {s}; }` is legal.

Comment: In short: Do what you feel is correct, and simply be consistent in your usage. It's best to have as little variation in your notation as possible imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as an "Array Initializer". It's a shorthand (syntactic sugar) <strike>introduced in JDK 5</strike> that has existed since 1.0 (*credit to Andy and Holger* below).

```java
float[] values = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
```

The latter is the traditional way to assign an array.

```java
float[] values2 = new float[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
```

You can use whichever makes you feel more comfortable.

---

Keep in mind that the shorthand is only allowed during initialization.

```java
public class ArrayInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] values;
        values = new float[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }; // Valid

        float[] values2;
        values2 = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }; // Invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: I can’t remember a Java version where this didn’t work. So it’s either, added in Java 1.1 or even existed from day one. It’s definitely *not* “introduced in JDK 5”.

Comment: @Holger https://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/10.doc.html#11358 there in the Java 1.0 spec.

Comment: btw you can also create an array without "new" to specify annotation properties of array type.

Answer (score 2):

The omittance of `new float[]` is simply a shorthand. As mentioned by Andy Turner, this shorthand syntax is only allowed in a variable *declaration*. That being said, the two lines compile into identical bytecode.

Take this class for example:

```
public class Test {
    float[] values = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    float[] values2 = new float[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
}
```

The compiled bytecode is equivalent to:

```
public class Test {
    float[] values;
    float[] values2;

    public Test() {
        super();
        this.values = new float[] { 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f, 50.0f };
        this.values2 = new float[] { 10.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f, 40.0f, 50.0f };
    }
}
```

Comment: "this shorthand syntax can only be used when the array elements are known at the time of assignment" the shorthand syntax can only be used in a variable declaration. Even if you know the elements, you can't write e.g. `values = { 10 };`, only `float[] values = { 10 };`.

Comment: Note that the type of the LHS informs the component type of the RHS literal. Obviously, the compiled code is the same only when it's compilable, and since you can only assign a literal when declaring the array, `T[] arr = new T[] {...}` may become `T[] arr = {...}`. That's the only context you can actually leave it off, when you already have (a non-generic) `T[]` on the LHS.

Comment: @Holger I was referring to the fact that you can only use curly braces to "construct" the array. I decided to remove that part because it still applies to both approaches presented in the question.